# PhantomJS - Render image per page

Tags: phantomjs

So I am in the process of migrating to PhantomJS to render our PDFs & Screen Scrapes for our site. Everything is pretty much figured out except for one thing that is giving me problems.

Is it possible to use PhantomJS to render a single image per 'page' in a document? similar to how it does paging in PDF except for a new image for each one of the pages.

Answer (score 1):

> similar to how it does paging in PDF

I suppose you are talking about [paperSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html) property.

> render a single image per 'page'

What if you simply "move" clipRect page-by-page, rendering each pass intro separate file?
Something like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var pageHeight = 600;
var pageWidth = 400;
var index = 0;
var maxPages = 5;

page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };

function takeNextPage() {
    page.clipRect = {
        top: index * pageHeight,
        left: 0,
        width: pageWidth,
        height: pageHeight
    };

    page.render('page' + index + '.png');

    if (++index < maxPages) {
        takeNextPage();
    } else {
        phantom.exit();
    }
}

page.open('http://...', function() {
    takeNextPage();
});
```

Comment: Not a bad idea at all although ideally, it would listen to the page breaks defined in the CSS. This is a great starting point for me so thank you very much for the suggestion.